# How to prevent wordpress from redirecting media attachment page to media page?

Tags: redirect, media, attachments

For some reason googlebot tried to index my media attachment pages and got redirected to media pages.

This seems to be a default wordpress behavior.
To recreate it, upload an image called test.jpg to a wordpress installation. Create a post called my-post and add the media "test" to my-post using the wordpress editor.
Then, if you request mydomain.com/my-post/test/ it will redirect to mydomain.com/test/

I have tried to add to functions.php the following:

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'disable_media_attachment_redirect');
function disable_media_attachment_redirect() {
if (is_attachment()) {
    global $wp_query;
    $wp_query->set_404();
    status_header(404);
    nocache_headers();
}}
```

When I request mydomain.com/my-post/test/ it first 301 redirects to mydomain.com/test/ and then returns a 404. I would like mydomain.com/my-post/test/ to return a 404 right from the beginning because googlebot visits mydomain.com/my-post/test/ and sees that it is a redirect, but never visits the mydomain.com/test/ which returns the 404 and shows googlebot that it should exclude this URL.

Answer (score 0):

Yoast SEO (and probably other SEO plugins as well) handles that [issue by redirecting to the image itself](https://yoast.com/help/yoast-seo-settings-media-pages/).

I'm not sure how they do it, but you can either go the quick route and install the plugin, or you try to look trough the [code](https://github.com/Yoast/wordpress-seo) to decipher it for your own code.

Otherwise, this is maybe better handled by adding something to robots.txt?